# What is the next term of the sequence? I don't know whether it is arithmetic or geometric...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know whether it is arithmetic sequence or geometric sequence so...

$4,9,11,23,16,33,22,\dots$

I've tried but there is 5 possibilities: $11,22,23,44$ or $45$.

Comment: What exactly is a geographic sequence ? Do you perhaps mean a geometric one ?

Comment: yes! I'm sorry thats what I meant thank you!!

Comment: Out of curiosity what makes you think there exist a unique next integer?

Answer (score 2):

It is obviously neither arithmetic, nor geometric. However, you might be able to figure something out by grouping the items in your list by consecutive pairs: $(4,9)$, $(11, 23)$ etc. Then check that the value you guessed for the next item belongs to the possible set.